# How to click on the table cell for particular text

Tags: ruby, html-table, cell, watir

The following is the DOM details:

```
<div id: "abc_440"
 <table class = "listtable"   >
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td id = "someid"   >
       <td class = 'someclass_item"> This is Text </td>
       <td class = 'someclass_button">
          < a > Add </a>
       </td>    
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

I need to click on 'Add' for particular text at "This is Text". I have to use div with ID (abc_440)to locate the corresponding table as there are may divs with this same dom layout. but index at div ID (for example 440) keeps changing to random number. How do I handle it in general ?

Please help.

Comment: What do you need to do after the click?

Comment: Is this an asp page? Or plain html?

Comment: After click of Add, at a space is added & i work on couple of Ui things there & then again repeat the click action for other text. I am not sure on how to know if this is a asp page.

Comment: Can you post the code in his context? It's not normal that the id is modify. Either you are in a page processed by the server which edit the div Id (Id of element in ASP page are auto generated), or you do some weird js edit that modify the div Id.

Comment: Check the file extension. I just want to know if its a plain `html` (`.html`) or a server page (`.aspx`, `.jsp`, `.cshtml`, ...)

Comment: When I am using firebug, I see its just HTML.

Comment: I meant the source file...

Comment: yes, its just html. I am viewing the source file & it starts & ends with <html>. I am trying to use watir-ruby for my automation test.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix quotes in HTML tags.  `id:` doesn't work.  `<td>`s should rarely be empty. The Add button should be a button, not an `<a>nchor` element.  Buttons only work in `<form>`s.

```
<form id="abc_440" action='someURI'>  <!-- The handler for the button. -->
    <table class="listtable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id = "someid">
                    <!-- What goes here? -->
                </td>
                <td class='someclass_item'>
                    This is Text
                </td>
                <td class='someclass_button'>
                    <button name='add'>Add</button>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

You should be able to find the button through its `name` attribute, *add*, and through the form's `id` attribute, abc_440.  Who generates the `id`s?

Once you have the problem of finding the add button solved, and figuring out where the form's id comes from, please then stop using tables for formatting.  There's no need for that.  Learn about `<form>`s, `<fieldset>`s, `<legend>`s, and `<label>`s. I doubt you need the *some_id* part, the text part should probably be a `<label>`, and you can use CSS to format your `<label>`s as:

```
label {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
fieldset p {
    clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is very similar to the [previous Watir question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503662/using-watir-to-click-table-element-without-id).

Given that the id is randomly generated, it does not sounds like a good way of finding the link. You will likely need to use the text of the same row.

Assuming that the "This is Text" is unique (as you said you want to find the Add link for it), you can find that td, go to the parent row and then get the link.

```
b.td(:text => 'This is Text').parent.link.click
```

If you need to ensure that the text is in the second column, then you can do:

```
b.trs.find{ |tr| 
    tr.td.exists? and tr.td(:index => 1).text == 'This is Text'
}.link.click
```

The `tr.td.exists?` is added in case some of your rows do not have any tds (example a header row), which would cause an exception when checking the second criteria.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept it as an answer.  It helps keep SO tidy...